# Statistics module has less functionality

Tags: 8, nodes

The [official documentation for the statistics](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/statistics/overview) module lists some exciting features. Here is a quote of what I found there.

> **Viewing site usage**
>
> The Statistics module can help you break down details about your users and how they are using the site. The module offers four reports:
>
> - Recent hits displays information about the latest activity on your site, including the URL and title of the page that was accessed, the user name (if available) and the IP address of the viewer.
> - Top referrers displays where visitors came from (referrer URL).
> - Top pages displays a list of pages ordered by how often they were viewed.
> - Top visitors shows you the most active visitors for your site and allows you to ban abusive visitors.

Unfortunately I don't  see any of those functionalities in my drupal 8 site. All I see is the number of views on a node, and no way to see the IP addresses, or referal URL or any of the above functionalities. Looking at the source code, I also don't see where the above functionalities are implemented.

What do I need to do to get the functionalities listed above?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a feature request for a contributed module and needs to be discussed in the issue queues on Drupal.org

Answer (score 2):

Based on Drupal 8.3.1, it appears that documentation is incorrect. Well, they seem to primarily relate to Drupal 7.

The statistics module doesn't appear to store IP addresses or user names.

The module does provide a popular content block, which is based on view statistics.

The module also provides views integration, so you can create reports that have statistics data using views, but it doesn't add any default views similar to the reports mentioned in those docs.

Comment: Okay...what module could offer those functionalities listed there? I tried the visitors module but its buggy and couldnt work..almost destroyed my site

Comment: Depending on what your specific requirements are, Google Analytics is a possible solution.

Comment: I want authors to see visitors who viewed their content. Google analytics seems to be a good choice for me as the owner, but for the other content creators, they need minimal analytics. Kinda like what youtube offers content creators..without them going to google analytics

Comment: I haven't yet seen a Drupal 8 module that provides that functionality (that's not to say that one doesn't exist, it might). You might have to go custom in this case.

Comment: Did anyone find a decent Drupal 8 module for this functionality?  I'm missing the 'track' tab on each node that Drupal 7 has...